# Flat product/category tables producing category URL instead of product on list view

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products, product-urls, flat-catalog, flat-indexer

I have enabled the flat product and category tables on a development site to test before using live, and for some reason product links in category views now link back to the category itself rather than through to the category.

Has anyone experienced this before?  Is this a quick fix that I'm just missing or is it going to be a long dredge through the codebase?

Comment: Could you try reindex clear the cache and try again

Comment: Actually my other question I've just posted is about this, I need to enable them on a live site but they haven't been reindedxed for 2 years and I can't leave them up with old data for 20+ minutes while they reindex, is it possible to reindex without having them enabled?

Comment: Although saying this yes I reindexed on dev and it still had the same issue

Comment: you mean, you want to reindex without enabling the flat product and category, yes you can disable it from Admin panel and try re-indexing. If it is production website, please have backup of old database before you proceed with your process.

Comment: Reindexing from n98 does not run for enough time for me to think it's running properly in production, and when they're disabled they don't appear in the manage indexes screen